# MS Access: Assign variable for Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, global-variables

I am trying to set up a global variable (as form) and set it = Form_MyForm

I have used the Form Load event to make the assignment and since it is a global variable I am expecting all my procedures can use this variable of mine without me retyping the assignment in different procedures

Problem is that sometimes it works while at others times it fails to recognise my variable, at which point I have to close my form and re-open it to refresh the assignment

I looked at the many Event for Access Forms but not sure what they are and how they can be helpful to my situation

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Are you sure you are using vb.net? if this is within Access, it would be vba instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your global variable(s) in an Access **module** (not behind any form). This allows any object (form, report, macro etc.) to have access to them.
2. Initialize the variables inside a Public Function or Public Sub within the module and have the function/sub called by the database's opening form (i.e., main menu or switchboard).
3. Now, variables can be used in expressions, queries, VBA, and other areas. 
   **If the global variable needs to be redefined by various parameters, set that up in the function/sub and re-call it from a specific trigger event.

Comment: Sorry for late response, internet went away at my end!! To answer the responses
1- Yes I am using a modules just for declaration

Comment: Sorry for late response, internet went away at my end!! To answer the responses
1- Yes I am using a modules just for declaration
2- I initialize the variable when the form is opened i.e On Load event , and it works fine for a while but after a while some of my procedures stop recognising that variable
3- I just have a static variable which should reference this form of mine. I am not sure which event would keep on refreshing the variable assignment

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I am developing an application so when I open the application fresh it works fine but while I am working on a sub or function the variable assignment stops being recognised

Comment: By "working" do you mean coding in VBA? Or running the other subs and functions in the runtime of application? Sometimes jumping in and out of the VBA development environment may turn off the global scope since the Access session may have ended. Hence, after each code change, you my need to re-initialize the variables (i.e., re-start application). If global variables are not being recognized during course of application, then it is a coding issue which will help if we can see specific VBA code.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I was coding in vba as well as trying new subs and functions and jumping back and forth the access and vba UI; this is probably why my variable stopped being recognised at times

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with user defined global variables, any time there is an error thrown or you switch to the development environment, you lose the set value in the variable.
You could try using a Session Variable, from the TempVar collection, which I find to be much more stable. It is stays set until you close the Database or you unset it.

```
MyFormName = me.Form.Name
'Load the data into Session variables
TempVars.Add "SessMyFormName", MyFormName
'Use the value elsewhere
SelectedForm = TempVars![SessMyFormName]
'Remove All Session Variables Set Earlier
TempVars.RemoveAll 'Destroy Session
```